# Tailwind CSS Position Footer at bottom of page when page content height is set to h-full

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I need a footer that is always at the bottom of the page - at the moment, the page content style is `h-full grow` s.t. it takes up the entire screen, and if additional content is rendered it will expand downward. When adding my footer, it always expands the page and is just beneath the limit of the screen

```
const SafeAreaPage = ({ children, isHideSidebar, isIgnoreMobileTabs }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className="safearea-pad-y bg-color-bg-lightmode-primary flex h-full grow flex-col">
      {!isHideSidebar && <SidebarNav />}
      {/* This is the wrapper for the content of the site */}
      <div
        className={classNames(
          'flex h-fit grow flex-col lg:pb-0',
          !isIgnoreMobileTabs && 'pb-tabs',
          !isHideSidebar && 'lg:pl-side-nav',
        )}
      >
        {children}
          <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

the `children` components often have the property `h-full`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a flex column (`flex-col`) container that should expand to fill the viewport height (`h-full grow`). However, when `children` components also have the `h-full` property, they might take up all available space, pushing the `Footer` beyond the viewport, especially when the content is more than what can fit on the screen.

Make sure you add `min-h-screen` for the outermost container so that it takes up at least the full height of the viewport.

Add `flex-grow` to the `div` that wraps both content and footer. It'll make sure that the inner `div` will expand to take up any available space within the outer container.

Then create a content wrapper `div` and add `flex-grow` to expand to fill any available space like above also pushing the footer to the bottom of the screen when the content is short. Also add `h-auto` so that this wrapper only takes up as much space as its content needs.

Try this out:

```
const SafeAreaPage = ({ children, isHideSidebar, isIgnoreMobileTabs }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className="safearea-pad-y bg-color-bg-lightmode-primary flex flex-col min-h-screen">
      {!isHideSidebar && <SidebarNav />}
      {/* Main content + footer wrapper */}
      <div
        className={`flex flex-col flex-grow ${
          !isHideSidebar ? 'lg:pl-side-nav' : ''
        }`}
      >
        {/* Content wrapper */}
        <div
          className={`flex-grow ${
            !isIgnoreMobileTabs ? 'pb-tabs' : ''
          } lg:pb-0 flex flex-col h-auto`}
        >
          {children}
        </div>
        {/* Footer */}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```